# C/C++ pointer tricks (saving pointer to int, and translating back)

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, void-pointers

As title says, I'm currently doing some small hacks with pointers in C++, but something isn't working out here's what I got:

```
uintptr_t texture_pointer = (int)((void*) &texture);
```

Where texture is a class; this seems to work fine, as I'm getting a pointer value out, and I have insured that I'm getting the same value into my other function, which is supposed to get the object back; this is the code that fails:

```
std::cout << "C++ BEFORE: " << texture_pointer << std::endl;
Texture texture = *(Texture*)((void*) texture_pointer);
std::cout << "C++ AFTER: " << (uintptr_t)((void*) &texture) << std::endl;
```

The output I was excepting; was that the same number for both, however I'm getting two different numbers, hence why I think there must be an error, but I can't seem to find it.

Example output:

```
C++ BEFORE: 2685236
C++ AFTER: 2684960
```

Comment: "Some small hacks with pointers in C++" is almost never a good idea.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: on many 64 bits architectures sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*), check this.

Comment: is there subclassing involved?

Comment: @@Ben doesn't the uintptr_t insure that it's the same size?

Comment: @@Simone no, I don't think so, what difference does it make?

Comment: @@Oli Charlesworth I'm saving the pointer, in lua.

Comment: @Skeen: I don't know anything about Lua.  Why does it force you to store pointers in integer types?

Comment: Please don't do this. Save yourself hours of pain and recoding. Please don't do this.

Comment: @Oli: Lua has a `userdata` type for passing C structs about the place, but AFAIK that's a Lua object and is garbage collected. If you want a pointer to a C struct whose lifetime is managed by C, then AFAIK the idiom is to use an integer as an opaque handle. I suppose you could use a `userdata` containing only a pointer, and that would be safer since it really is opaque to Lua code. But I don't know very far, I've never actually used Lua, so I'll delete this when someone provides a proper answer!

Comment: @@Pete Wilson I ended up not doing this, so don't worry.

Comment: @@Oli Charlesworth Lua doesn't really have support for pointers, as it's garbage collected.

Comment: @@Steve Jessop There is actually something called a light_userdata object, that is not subject to the garbage collection, and used to model C pointers, but this isn't of any use to me, sadly.

Comment: @Skeen: could you define (in C++) `struct my_opaque_handle { Texture *ptr; };`, then when your pointer needs to venture out into Lua code, pass a `userdata` of that struct, containing the pointer value, instead of an integer containing the reinterpreted pointer value?

Comment: I guess I could, but I changed the design now :), thanks anyways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line:

```
Texture texture = *(Texture*)((void*) texture_pointer);
```

creates a **new** `Texture` object as a copy of the original one.  Obviously, this has a different address to the old one.

You could do this:

```
Texture &texture = *(Texture*)((void*) texture_pointer);
```

(i.e. create a reference to the old one).

But in general, messing about with pointers like this is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks you for the solution, I can however gladly inform; I will not be using it. - Made a prettier, and safer, though slower solution instead.

Answer (score 4):

For casting to and from void pointers, use `static_cast`. For casting to and from integers, use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
SomeType* p;

// Make sure the type can hold a pointer.
std::uint64_t i = reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(p);

...

SomeType* q = reinterpret_cast<SomeType*>(i); // Guaranteed to yield p back
```

Comment: Is this portable?  I'm concerned about the assumption that 64-bit is guaranteed to be big enough.

Comment: Wouldn't it be portable, with <uintptr_t>?

Answer (score 1):

As well as the errors pointed out already in other answers, this line is incorrect and may well fail on 64 bit systems (LP64):

```
uintptr_t texture_pointer = (int)((void*) &texture);
```

It should be:

```
uintptr_t texture_pointer = (uintptr_t)&texture;
```

(assuming you want to use C-style casts rather than proper C++ casts for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you take the address of an object allocated on the stack, not on the heap. The line:

```
Texture texture = *(Texture*)((void*) texture_pointer);
```

then copies that object into another object allocated on the stack. Then you take the address of the second address.

As you are dealing with two different objects, you have two different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If I have counted the '*'s correctly this line

```
Texture texture = *(Texture*)((void*) texture_pointer);
```

creates a copy of whatevery texture_pointer points to.

so, texture and *texture_pointer are different storage locations and that's why &texture and texture_pointer have different values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Texture texture = *(Texture*)((void*) texture_pointer);
```

This line creates a new object and assigns the object pointed to by texture_pointer to it. That's different from creating a pointer and making it point to an object. When you assign one object to another, you're basically copying contents of the old one into the new one. It makes sense, then, that the two printed addresses are different -- they're the addresses of two different objects.